# Salesforce API call through POST man

Tags: postman, salesforce, rest

I am unable to get records from sales force using postman GET method .
https://mysit.lightning.force.com/services/data/v42.0/query?q=SELECT+name,type+from+Account
Used Headers :
Authentication : Bearer 00C030000004a2z!AQoAQII0XyApL6OBs4sBPAVbPj1E_EFpvYUw3Sc0ruOhwKDz493Jo2WZrV0b248KOQLEqeMT665S4Gexp154LrwHxBLOtTJU

I got post amn status 411 length required issue .

Any one guide me how to resolve my issue  .

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer to [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.

Do you have a typo here or is that the correct error response: `post amn status 411 length required` ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_usage_rest_resources.htm?search_text=content-length), you have to set `Content-Length`.

If you still get the 411-error **you are not using a real GET-Request**

**Example**:

```
req.setHeader('Content-Length', '4096');
```

It appears, however, if you use a **GET** Request, you do not have to send the `Content-Length` parameter.

**Solution:** Either use GET-Method or set Content-Length.

---

**Sidenote:** Avoid GET Requests if they are not strictly required, since these requests will be non-private and most likely even logged in server logs, etc.